# Differential Equations Escape Velocity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can somebody tell me how I might solve the following differential equation?
$$\frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2} = \frac{k}{x(t)^2}$$
k is a constant

Comment: What context did the equation show up in?

Comment: Autonomous equation. Let $v(x)=x'(t)$. The equation for $v$ is $v'v=\frac{1}{2}(v^2)'=kx^{-2}$. Integrate to find $v(x)$. Separate variables and integrate again to find $t(x)$. The solution is the inverse $x(t)$, which probably cannot be found 'nicely'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply both sides by $dx/dt$:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{k}{x^2} \frac{dx}{dt}
$$
Notice that this implies the following:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left[ \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 \right] = \frac{d}{dt} \left[ - \frac{k}{x} \right]
$$
This implies that the difference between the quantities in square brackets is a constant with respect to $t$, which can be determined from the initial conditions.  You then have a first-order ODE instead:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 = - \frac{k}{x} + C.
$$
This is a separable first-order ODE and can be solved by standard techniques (though IIRC there does not exist a closed-form solution for $x(t)$, only for $t(x)$.)

A few other notes:

- The constant $C$ has a nice physical interpretation which I will leave for you to discover. If $k < 0$, the solutions will have different forms depending on whether $C$ is positive, negative, or zero.
- If $k > 0$, the problem as posed would be the equation of motion being *repelled* by an inverse-square force.  This may or may not have been your intention, since you're talking about escape velocity in the title.  For an attractive force, be sure to take $k < 0$.

Comment: Hey! Sorry to ask such dumb question but can you explain how did you write (dx/dt)(d²x/dt²) equal to d/dt[(dx/dt)²/2]. I get that when you integrate this you get 1/2 but how did you get this on the very next step?

Comment: @MWD: it's one of those "standard tricks" that's easier to see going the other direction.  Note that using the chain rule, the derivative of $(f')^2$ is $2f' f''$.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to solve the problem. You have
$$x''=\frac k{x^2}$$ Switch variables to have
$$-\frac {t''}{[t']^3}=\frac k{x^2}$$ Now, reduction of order $p=t'$
$$\frac {p'}{p^3}=-\frac k{x^2} \implies  -\frac{1}{2 p^2}=\frac k x +c_1\implies p=t'=\pm \sqrt{c_2-2\frac k x}$$

$$t+c_3=\pm\Bigg[x \sqrt{c_2-\frac{2 k}{x}}-\frac{k \log \left(\sqrt{c_2} x \sqrt{c_2-\frac{2 k}{x}}+c_2
   x-k\right)}{\sqrt{c_2}}\Bigg]$$ which, I am afraid, would be probably impossible to inverse